# Why Inner Join worked as Cross Join in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to join several tables using `INNER JOIN`.

Here is code

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpRecData') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #tmpRecData

--STEP 1
SELECT DISTINCT 
    pr.ChainID, pr.StoreID, pr.SupplierID, pr.ProductID, 
    MAX(CAST(pr.ActiveLastDate AS date)) AS 'Active Date'
    --ChainID, SupplierID, StoreID, InvoiceDate, InvoiceNumber, SupplierInvoiceDate, SupplierInvoiceNumber
INTO 
    #tmpRecData 
FROM 
    dbo.[ProductPrices_Retailer] AS pr
LEFT JOIN 
    ProductIdentifiers iden ON pr.ProductID = iden.ProductID
                            AND iden.ProductIdentifierTypeID = 2
WHERE 
    pr.ChainID = '119121'
    AND pr.ActiveLastDate > '12/01/2016'                  
GROUP BY 
    pr.ProductID, pr.ProductName, iden.IdentifierValue, 
    pr.ChainID, pr.StoreID, pr.SupplierID

--STEP 2
SELECT 
    rec.ChainID, rec.StoreID, rec.SupplierInvoiceNumber,
    rec.TransactionTypeID, rec.SupplierID, rec.SaleDateTime,
    rec.ProductID, rec.UPC, rec.ProductDescriptionReported, 
    rec.RawProductIdentifier 
FROM 
    #tmpRecData t
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.StoreTransactions AS rec WITH (NOLOCK) ON rec.ChainID = T.ChainID 
WHERE 
    rec.ChainID = '119121'

DROP TABLE #tmpRecData
```

I am getting 4096 (Step1) * 145979 (Step2) = 725077693 rows (725 million)

This is a huge number of records, but I have used `INNER JOIN`, so why it worked as CROSS JOIN?

Comment: You are only joining on the ChainID - and they all have the same chainID based on the where clause. Are there other columns linking the data you need to add to the ON clause?

Comment: Yes there were some other columns to join but on that we were getting 0 records. ChainID was the only join criteria which gave data

Comment: @PraveenSingh You can't just try every column as the join criteria until you guess the correct one. If you're getting 0 records maybe you're supposed to get 0 records?

Comment: INNER JOIN can become a CROSS JOIN if the logical criteria use in the ON clause is always true - similarly CROSS JOIN can be made to return the same records as an INNER JOIN via logic in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

CROSS JOIN is very different to INNER JOIN.

INNER JOIN displays only the rows that have a match in both the joined tables..

CROSS JOIN produces a Cartesian product of the tables in the join. The number of rows of the result is the number of the rows in first table multiplied by the number of rows in the second table.

Comment: Yes, it's true but if I gatting 4096 records in step 1 then after joining I must get 4096 records only. But our DBA says it worked as CROSS JOIN

Answer (score 0):

You need to join with store ID in step2 for this to work. It is running chainID for every store , hence too many number of records. If products also need to match, then you need to Join productID as well in step2

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpRecData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpRecData

 --STEP 1
  SELECT DISTINCT pr.ChainID,pr.StoreID,pr.SupplierID,pr.ProductID, MAX(CAST(pr.ActiveLastDate AS date)) AS 'Active Date'
  --ChainID, SupplierID, StoreID, InvoiceDate, InvoiceNumber, SupplierInvoiceDate, SupplierInvoiceNumber
        INTO #tmpRecData 
        FROM dbo.[ProductPrices_Retailer] AS pr
            LEFT JOIN ProductIdentifiers iden
                    ON pr.ProductID=iden.ProductID
                    AND iden.ProductIdentifierTypeID=2
        WHERE pr.ChainID='119121'
              AND pr.ActiveLastDate>'12/01/2016'                  
        GROUP BY pr.ProductID,pr.ProductName,iden.IdentifierValue,pr.ChainID,pr.StoreID,pr.SupplierID


 --STEP 2

 SELECT rec.ChainID,rec.StoreID,rec.SupplierInvoiceNumber,rec.TransactionTypeID,rec.SupplierID,rec.SaleDateTime,
         rec.ProductID,rec.UPC,rec.ProductDescriptionReported,rec.RawProductIdentifier 
    FROM #tmpRecData t
     INNER JOIN dbo.StoreTransactions AS rec WITH (NOLOCK)  
      ON rec.ChainID=T.ChainID and rec.StoreID = T.storeID
   WHERE rec.ChainID='119121'

   DROP TABLE #tmpRecData
```

Comment: I agreed and tried already but there were no such matching records with chain id and store id or with any other